# Arch Linux Booting issues

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, bootloader

I just installed `Arch Linux` using https://archlinuxgui.in/

But, when I am booting normally nothing shows up but a black screen.
I restarted my system multiple times and nothing happens and I am stuck on the black screen.

So I plugged in my `Ventoy USB` with `Arch Linux Image` in it.  Instead of showing the `Ventoy Booting page` it showed me `Arch Linux Bootloader`.

I can boot into my Arch Linux with the USB plugged in but I can't boot without it.  I think that I have my bootloader installed on that USB. How can I install it on my main Hard Drive instead of my USB?

```
OS : Arch Linux 64 Bit ( Installed using https://archlinuxgui.in/)\
Kernal : 5.18.5-arch1-1\
DE : XFCE
```